# Electrum wallet file

Tags: wallet, electrum

Are all the information of my wallet stored inside the wallet file that I can find in the folder "wallet", inside the .electrum folder?

For instance, I can copy this file on another pc and just paste it into the "wallet" folder to have access to my BTC again, right?  (assuming that I know the wallet password)

I know that I can restore the whole wallet with the master seed, I was just curios if this method works also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All of the information about your wallet is stored in the file of the same name as your wallet in the `wallet` folder of the electrum datadir. Copying that file elsewhere will allow you to keep all labels and comments on your addresses and transactions.